# Error Code -36 | unable to undo delete file operation using ⌘ Z

Tags: finder, permission

I deleted some files, and they are available in Bin.
If I try to undo the delete attempt by pressing `⌘ Z`, it gives me the below errors:  [image]

**My Observations:**

I found there are 2 `Bin`s; if I open `Get Info` for both, the difference I see is - 1 has Kind=Folder, other has Kind=Bin.

The Bin (Folder) is available at: /Users/shripalmehta/

But Bin (Bin) has no path.

If I drag and drop a file into Bin (Folder), it appears in Bin (Bin) as well, and such file can be reverted just as normally we would (from either of the Bins).
But if I press `⌘ ⌫` it goes directly into Bin (Bin) and it becomes unrecoverable!

How do I fix this? Is is some kind of Permission issue?

**Edit:**

1. I'm using MacOS Big Sur 11.6 on MacBook Air M1 (2020)
2. Added My Observations above

Comment: What happens if you just drag them back to where they came from, or to the desktop? You can only Undo if the very last step before that was the delete.

Comment: It is the very last step.
Also, it doesn't allow drag and drop either! When I drag and drop the file from Bin to Desktop, the file disappears from both locations, completely unable to recover!!

Comment: I even tried doing ⌘ C + ⌘ V but even then the file disappears from both locations!

Comment: Error -36 is a data error. It cannot either identify, or correctly read from the original location, or have permission to write to the 'return' location. Check where the files were before delete. That the files are named by `id` rather than actual name, suggests it cannot correctly find them in the Bin. I'd run Repair from Disk Utility as a first step, but make sure your backup is up to date.

Comment: I found there are 2 ```Bin```s, if I open ```Get Info``` for both, the difference I see is, 1 has Kind = Folder, other has Kind = Bin.
The Bin (Folder) is available at: /Users/shripalmehta/ but Bin (Bin) has no path.
If I drag and drop a file into Bin (Folder), is appears in Bin (Bin) as well, and such file can be reverted just as normally we would.
But if I press ⌘⌫ it goes directly into Bin (Bin) and it becomes unrecoverable!

Comment: `bin` is not what you're looking for. Deleted files go to `Trash`. There are multiple `Trash` locations, one for the system, one per user & one per attached volume. Don't try figure out how they map. Run Disk Utility on the volume the files were on before deletion.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335092/trash-directories-on-mac-how-to-find-them-and-how-to-properly-clear-them

Comment: In MacOS Big Sur 11.x, the Trash is renamed as Bin

Comment: Since Catalina, but that's just a user-facing name. If you're going to dig around [which I still recommend you shouldn't] in Terminal you'll find it's still actually called Trash. I highly recommend you do not mess with the Trash structure unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I just upgraded from Big Sur (11.6) to Monterey (12.0.1) and the issue seems to be resolved! So, I'm assuming that it was a minor bug in one of the patches, and that it was fixed in this new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue a while back, and one day it just fixed itself, though here is the workaround I used.

---

1. Open up terminal
2. type `mv`  (space is important) and then drag the file from the trash into the terminal window. (It is important to drag the file, because whenever this happened to me, the file was not in ~/.trash)
3. Type where you want the file to be moved to (e.g. to move to your downloads type `~/downloads`, you can also just drag the folder from finder).

Example: `mv /users/yourname/.trash/deletedfile ~/downloads`

Comment: It got fixed when I upgraded the macOS to Monterey.